# Mathematica 9, Mavericks, Java

Tags: version-9, mac-os-x, java

I've been trying to get a clear story regarding the interaction of these three components before upgrading my system from Lion to Mavericks --- I can't afford a Mathematica disaster.

What I think is the case is:
1. Upgrading to Mavericks removes Java from the system (or perhaps installs Java 7).
2. MMA 9 requires Java 6, and the MMA installer gives you an option to install (downgrade?) to Java 6.
3. Once you have Java 6 installed, MMA works fine.

Does that sound correct? Does Wolfram indeed support MMA 9 on Mavericks?

Comment: Yes, v9 works fine on Mavericks. The steps you describe are what's necessary.

Comment: You don't need to bother with Java at all.  Apple provides Java 6, and this is what Mathematica uses.  When I upgraded to Mavericks, Apple Java 6 was automatically removed.  Mathematica was one of the first programs I started up afterwards.  The OS automatically prompted me to install Apple Java 6, and after a click of a single button and a few minutes to download it, everything was working perfectly.

Comment: This article explains Java on Mavericks: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12098

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only agree with Szabolcs comment. Upgrading to Mavericks brought a lot of problems, but *Mathematica* worked from the first minute. Therefore, let me cite the comment into an answer:

> You don't need to bother with Java at all. Apple provides Java 6, and this is what Mathematica uses. When I upgraded to Mavericks, Apple Java 6 was automatically removed. Mathematica was one of the first programs I started up afterwards. The OS automatically prompted me to install Apple Java 6, and after a click of a single button and a few minutes to download it, everything was working perfectly.

And here is the link to an official Woflram article which KAI posted:

- [Reinstalling Java after Updating OS X](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12098)

Comment: It all worked as advertised. Thanks for the help, all.